# Create and change to new view with React Native

Tags: android, ios, authentication, reactjs, native

We're currently working on an app for one of our customers, and we've decided to use React Native as the technology to use for creating the app.

I'm pretty new to this technology, and I'm used to developing apps with either C# or Java, where I have full-fledged IDEs that provide all the functionality I need.

I'm currently creating a login screen, and would like to change to different views, depending on the type of login (e.g.: Facebook, Google, Twitter, Email, etc.).

How do I go about doing this. As I mention, with an IDE, it'd be a shortcut like SHIFT+ALT+A or something to create a new item, select type, name it and the IDE does the rest.

Do I have to create a new xx.android/ios.js file, and somehow call that, or do I need to go in to the native backend of the different projects?

What I tried was something along the lines of:

```
class Class extends Component {
    render() {
        <UI code here>
        <Button onPress={this.eventHandler}
    }

    eventHandler(event) {
        var xxLogin = new xxLogin();
        xxLogin.render();
    }
}

class xxLogin extends Component {
    render() {
        <UI code here>
    }
}
```

But that failed, which I expected.

Thanks in advance for any help!

P.S.: I'm using Mac OS X El Capitan, if that helps.